# Should we announce chat on Meta site as a featured question

Tags: discussion, chat

People, please visit [The Appendix](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/the-appendix) (Ebooks.SE chat room) and discuss E-books (or anything else - no rules aside "be nice").

Or the Cat in the Hat buys it.

[image]